# Send a value by socket and read the value by reader.ReadInt32() changes value

Tags: c#, sockets, binary-data, binaryreader

I am trying to send a value by socket .So i have two parts in my project `Client` and `server` .

The `client` sends a value to server using this code :

```
           System.IO.BinaryWriter binaryWriter =
           new System.IO.BinaryWriter(networkStream);
           binaryWriter.Write(1);
           binaryWriter.Write(2);
           binaryWriter.Flush();
```

So in other part i need to read the two values i mean `1` and `2`;

So in server part i have this code :

```
  static void Listeners()
        {

        Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
        if (socketForClient.Connected)
        {
            NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);


            while (true)
            {
                  List<int> variables = new List<int>();
                using (var reader = new BinaryReader(networkStream))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {
                        int t = reader.ReadInt32();
                        variables.Add(t);
                    }
                }

      }
   }
}
```

As you can see i hold the values in `variables` list .but it doesn't work .i mean in server part i can't get the values `1` and `2` and my values is like this :841757955

best regards.

Comment: So how can i change it to binary ?

Comment: I'd assume you want to read the data as text. In the code you have provided you create `StreamReaders` and `StreamWriters` but then don't seem to use them. Rather than using `BinaryReader` in the server try using `StreamReader` instead.

Comment: No i should use binary ,but i don't know how can i do that? i will edit my post

Comment: Then use `BinaryWriter` instead of `StreamWriter`? The question definitely needs to be updated, and please remove the unused variables from your code snippets.

Comment: I update the post .please take a look .

Comment: @Daniel: Don't you think sending with `BinaryWriter` and reading with `BinaryWriter` should be compatible so far?

Comment: @peter_the_oak I'd expect sending with a `BinaryWriter` and reading with a *`BinaryReader`* to be compatible, which is not what was happening in the original version of this question.

Comment: So @DanielKelley i changed it as you said but it doesn't work

Comment: My values that i get in sever part is like this : 841757955

Comment: If you send "1,2" why do you expect the receiving side to receive 2 integers? Surely it will receive what you send? Unfortunately your question is very difficult to answer as it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Daniel: got it, sry :-)

Comment: Why my values that i receive is like this :841757955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your code, you are sending data as a string in binary format, this will yield bytes for the characters `1,2`.

When you read the data back you try to get Int32 values.

There are two options here:

Read and write data as a string.

```
 Client code:

 binaryWriter.Write("1,2");

 Server code:

 string text = binaryReader.ReadString(); // "1,2"
```

OR Read and write data as integers.

```
Client code:

binaryWriter.Write(10);
binaryWriter.Write(20);

Server code:

int value1 = binaryReader.ReadInt32(); //10
int value2 = binaryReader.ReadInt32(); //20
```

Comment: I use your code ,but the value that i receive in server is like this : = 855716097.Why ?

Answer (score 2):

> and my values is like this :841757955

Always worth sticking that number in the Windows calculator and convert that to hex.  You get 0x322C3503.

Which looks a lot like ASCII, a string with 3 characters that encodes "5,2".  In other words, your *real* code doesn't resemble your snippet at all, you don't actually use the BinaryWriter.Write(Int32) overload, you used BinaryWriter.Write(String).

Sure, that can't work, you can't write a string and expect it to be readable as raw integers.  Fix your code.

Comment: My project is a part of another project ,so i have to adaptive my project with other project

Comment: This is rather a drastic failure to communicate.  You not understanding this answer at all.  And worse, you not talking to the programmer that worked on the "other project".  Very hard to talk across a network if you don't know how to communicate.  I you wrote the "server" then you'll have to use BinaryReader.ReadString()

Comment: You know they give us a structure of their message that they send to our application and here you can see :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349052/read-variables-of-a-message-that-is-sent-by-a-server-using-socket

Comment: the picture is the structure of their message

Comment: Oh Lord, this involves trains?  You know you can kill a hundred people by getting this wrong?  Talk to your supervisor, you're in over your head.

Comment: :).You know it just a monitoring system .our project just gets the location of the trains and calculates the arrivaltime of the trains and show the time to the passenger by LCD monitor